# How to include the clients ip adress in to an audit as default constrain in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am writing av analytical standard solution register from the doping laboratory that i work for and got stuck on the problem how to get the ipaddress of the client in to the audit table.

I have found a straight forward method for actually get the ipaddress on the web and my question is not about that.

I got triggers on every table inserting records in to the audit table and I do not want to wright the inserting of the ipaddress manualy in every trigger. I would like to have something like a ***DEFAULT Constraint*** do the actual insertion of the  ipaddress, but when I try I get errors about sub Queries not allowed.

Here is the way to get the address,

```
SELECT     client_net_address
FROM       sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE     (session_id = @@SPID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL function as the DEFAULT constraint

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx.

If using SQL isnt enough, you can use a CLR function as a default constraint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Comment: Interesting, this behaviour isn't documented at all, but at least in SQL 2008 it worked for me: I could use a scalar function as a DEFAULT. Personally, I wouldn't rely on undocumented behaviour, and I would still go with the trigger solution because you might as well have all your auditing logic in one place. But it's good to know that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) specifies that a DEFAULT constraint can be "a constant, NULL, or a system function". Since there is no system function that returns the net address of the client, you cannot do what you want directly.

A trigger is the obvious solution here. Audit triggers are often created and maintained  automatically from a template anyway, because they are usually identical on all tables, and if you aren't doing this already then perhaps this would be a good opportunity to start. That would avoid your issue with manually adding the code everywhere.